# iPad Keynote Presentation in portrait mode

Tags: ipad, keynote

I'd like to use Keynote on iPad in portrait mode, so that I can use it while it's in my dock and so I can make app wireframes in it that are portrait mode apps (vertical orientation). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The only solution that I can find is to create the presentation in "normal" landscape orientation, and rotate every element sideways using `Inspector > Metrics > Rotation`. If I set everything to 90˚ then it shows up like I want it on the iPad.